# Server does not get message in a "Hello World" socket program

Tags: sockets, unix, go

I am practicing to use Unix socket together with bufio. This is the program:

```
    // Register server socket
    os.Remove("serversock")
    socket, err := net.ListenUnix("unix", &net.UnixAddr{"serversock", "unix"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go func() {
        for {
            // Accept new connection
            conn, err := socket.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Got connection")
            reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
            line, err := reader.ReadString(byte('\n'))
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Got line", line)
        }
    }()
    // Client connection
    conn, err := net.DialUnix("unix", nil, &net.UnixAddr{"serversock", "unix"})
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    n, err := writer.WriteString("hello world\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Written", n)
    // Client wait
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
```

When it runs, it prints:

```
Written 13
Got connection
```

And then exists, so the server does not seem to get the message. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writer is buffered, it doesn't flush the buffer when you `WriteString()` to it. Simply call `writer.Flush()` and it will actually send the line. You can also try writing directly to the socket and see what happens.

Also your accept loop should look like this:

```
go func() {
    for {
        // Accept new connection
        conn, err := socket.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Got connection")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

        //spawn a goroutine that has a read loop
        go func(reader *bufio.Reader) {
           for {
             line, err := reader.ReadString(byte('\n'))
             if err != nil {
                panic(err)
             }
             fmt.Println("Got line", line)
           }
        }(reader)
    }
}()
```